# Do I use "be" or "is" in this sentence?

Tags: verbs, subjunctive-mood, dependent-clause

Which of the following is correct?

> 1. I request that my proposal *is* communicated to the team for necessary action.
> 2. I request that my proposal *be* communicated to the team for necessary action.

I would appreciate further discussion on the topic so that I do not make similar mistakes or face this indecision in future.

Comment: ***Be***. The verb _request_ can take a tenseless _that_-clause complement, as well as an infinitive complement (_I requested that he do it, I requested him to do it_). However, _request_ **can't** take a tensed  _that_-clause: _*She requested that he is here_ is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Be* is the correct word.

For some helpful guidelines, check out Richard Nordquist's definition of "Subjunctive Mood" at *http://grammar.about.com/od/rs/g/subjuncterm05.htm*  He gives a nice overview of when and how to use it.

Best wishes!